# Removing source chunk from string.dump return value

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to make a closed-source lua file, and to do so, I'm taking the risk that noone in their right mind is going to take a long time converting (Is it some form of assembly) whatever string.dump returns.

However, string.dump also has a chunk of the string returned with the full source of the code dumped by it. No matter what I do, I can't seem to make an automatic source-code deleter that deletes the source from the returned string- It doesn't seem to be passed as-is, I don't know whether it removes my indenting, new lines, spaces, or it removes some under certain conditions or what.

So basically; say I had

```
local a = string.dump(function() print("Hello world") end)
```

a would be something like:

LuaQ (source) (the stuff I want to keep that makes it work I guess)

But I want to remove the source chunk, but string.find won't locate it even when I pass identical source in to find.

If I was unclear anywhere, please say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the source of [LuaC](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luac.c.html). I believe what you are seeing are just debugging informations, and LuaC has the option to strip debugging info out of a generated bytecode. You might take a look at how it does that.

That said, the string literals will always be visible in the bytecode of your program since Lua stores them as plain text in the bytecode.

Comment: Oh, so it uses it to know what to supply as an error if/when it errors? Would it still be operational if I removed this, and if I removed it, the source would no longer be there, is that right, or have I misinterpreted what you said?

Comment: @Ashley yes, it probably uses it to display the line on which an error occurred. Lua stores file checksums and sizes in the bytecode generated and checks to see if they are valid before running bytecode, so no, I don't think that if you manually removed it from the string it would still work. But people probably aren't going to take something from `string.dump` and try to run it with lua anyway, so it's up to you. You can probably just give them an empty string and that won't cause any harm either, I suppose, but it's up to you.

Comment: So whatever I do I'll need to release the source in some shape or form? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Ashley not necessarily. Lua detects automatically whether a chunk of code is bytecode or text, so if you wanted, you could compile your lua with luac with the `-s` flag to strip debug information, and distribute the bytecode which would now not include the plain-text source.

Answer (score 2):

After `a=string.dump(function() print("Hello world") end)`, `a` does *not* contain the source code for the function. It does contain the string in the function. though. However, you're probably using `loadstring` and the by default does add the complete strings as the name of the chunk. Try `loadstring(source,"=")` instead.

Comment: Yeah I'm using loadstring. What's the second argument do?

Comment: The second argument gives the name of the chunk that appears in error messages.